# Component binding through MarkupWriter - Tapestry

Tags: java, data-binding, tapestry

I'm currently in a situation where I need to use the `MarkupWriter` to create a checkbox instead of using `.tml`. But this is inside a component and I'd like to bind the checkbox's value to the parent's boolean value. In essence, it's the following:

**Component**

```
public class InnerComponent {
    @Parameter
    private boolean booleanValue;

    void afterRender(final MarkupWriter writer) {
        writer.element("input", "type", "checkbox");
        writer.end();
    }
}
```

**Calling page**

```
public class OuterPage {
    @Property
    private boolean checkboxValue;

    @InjectComponent
    private Zone booleanZone;

    Object onDisplayBoolean() {
        return booleanZone.getBody();
    }
}
```

**With .tml**

```
<html t:type="layout" title="testProject Index" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_4.xsd">
    <t:InnerComponent booleanValue='checkboxValue'/><br/>

    <t:eventlink event='displayBoolean' zone='booleanZone'>Update</t:eventlink>

    <t:zone t:id='booleanZone' id='booleanZone'>
        ${checkboxValue}
    </t:zone>
</html>
```

The component's `MarkupWriter` currently just writes out a simple checkbox. But it also receives the boolean as a parameter. How would I go about to bind the boolean parameter, to the checkbox the `MarkupWriter` generates?

In this simple example, checking the checkbox and then updating the `Zone` through the `EventLink` should show the updated value of the parent's `checkboxValue boolean`.

Answer (score 0):

Sifting through `Tapestry`'s source code, I have found *a* solution. My component should first of all extend `AbstractField` and then process the submission of the control. Reassigning the value with the updated one. Edited, it looks like the following:

```
public class InnerComponent extends AbstractField {
    @Property
    @Parameter
    private boolean booleanValue;

    @BeginRender
    void begin(final MarkupWriter writer) {
        writer.element("input", "type", "checkbox",
                "name", getControlName(),
                "id", getClientId(),
                "checked", booleanValue ? "checked" : null);
        writer.end();
    }

    @Override
    protected void processSubmission(String controlName) {
        String postedValue = request.getParameter(controlName);
        booleanValue = postedValue != null;
    }
}
```

This way I'm actually re-implementing the checkbox logic. Unlike in `.tml`, where I could be using the existing `Tapestry` `Checkbox` component. If there's a better solution, like using the existing `Checkbox` component, I'd be glad to hear.